# How filter by a foreign key on Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, filter, foreign-keys, crud

I'm trying to search on CRUD by a field that's a foreign key, but I allways get the error:

> Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains

That's was my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Subject
class SubjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['owner', 'name', 'slug']
    search_fields = ['owner', 'name', 'slug'] 
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}
admin.site.register(Subject, SubjectAdmin)
```

I saw on a forum that I need to change the "owner" by "owner__name", but now I get another error:

> Related Field got invalid lookup: name

My models.py:

```
from saga.accounts.models import User
class Subject(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True)
```

Comment: can you share your modals?

Comment: i have no idea what is happening but
1. owner__name = relate
2. owner.name = field in owner model

Comment: Tiny.D, I've edited the question with the models.py.